# Proving the Product of Unitary Matrices is also Unitary

Tags: linear-algebra

This is my attempt so far:
Suppose I have two unitary matrices, A and B, such that $A^*A=I$ and $B^*B=I$. We want to show that $(AB)^*(AB)=I$. So we have that
$$(AB)^*(AB)=B^*A^*AB=B^*IB=I.$$
Does this work as a proof? Do I need to show anything else?

Comment: Looks good ${}$

Comment: You have it!  Well done.